# Django REST framework: validate using request method

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to validate request method (POST, PUT, GET...) together with queryset in example below?

```
    def validate_title(self, value):
      qs = Place.objects.filter(title__iexact=value)
      if qs.exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplicated title")

      return value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could access the request method by using the serializer context as below,

```
def validate_title(self, value):
    request_method = self.context['request'].method # change is here
    qs = Place.objects.filter(title__iexact=value)
    if qs.exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Duplicated title")

    return value
```